# [DevCpp]Problems compiling program with curl library

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

Hello I want to compile a windows .EXE application using DevCpp with MinGW64 compiler. The application I want to compile is very simple and requires the CURL libraries. I am using Windows 8 64bit, Orwell Dev-C++ V 5.3.0.4. I have downloaded the CURL libraries from the official site (Win64 - MinGW64 devel v.28.1). I have copied all the include,bin and lib files to the MinGW64 folder but the program can not be compiled, as it gets the following linker errors:

```
            [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_init'
        [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_formadd'
        [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_formadd'
        [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_init'
        [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_slist_append'
        [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
        [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0x157): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
        [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0x173): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
        [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0x183): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_perform'
        [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0x19a): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_strerror'
        [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0x1cc): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_cleanup'
        [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0x1dc): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_formfree'
        [Linker error] C:\Users\Panos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSFo7Pn.o:upload.cpp:(.text+0x1ec): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_slist_free_all'
        collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The only was i managed to compile the program is with the -DCURL_STATICLIB -c -h -Icurl\include option to the compiler, but all I get is a 16bit application that is unable to run in my OS!

The code I am trying to compile is this CURL example:
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html

I have spent many hours searching the internet and reading guides to make my program compile but without any luck. Please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong!

Thanks!

Comment: These problems are not during the compilation process, but during the linking. You need to add paths to the libraries. You need to google how to tell the linker where to find the lib files. This is specific for the environment (in your case, Orwell Dev-C++ )

Comment: I have added the paths to the files via Tools>Compiler Options>Directories

Comment: Again, you need linker options, not compiler. By adding the directories to the compiler options, you've told Orwell Dev-C++ where to find the header files, not the compiler libraries. That's why the compilation is successful (it's before the linking problem). Find something about "Linker options"

Comment: There is no linker options option anywhere, but i can set command line options for the linker. How can I tell it to include the libs?

Comment: Depends on the environment, as I already said. I don't know how to do this for Orwell Dev-C++. For gcc, you add the paths to the libraries like this: `-L/full/or/relative/path/to/the/library -llabrary_name` (capital `-L` prefix for paths and lower-case `-l` prefix for the libraries)

Comment: -static-libgcc -LD:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\libcurl.a -llibcurl -LD:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\libcurl.dll -llibcurl
I have added the above, the program compiles, but when i run it, it says that libcurl.dll is missing from the computer :/

Comment: You don't need to put the library name in `-L`, `-L` shows only the path. And I don't know if this can be done for Windows. You should check the documentation of Orwell Dev-C++ or google how to do this.

Comment: If I dont add the .a file to the -L option I get the same linker problems. Ill get back to you i a while after i try something

Comment: Nope.... I have tried another guide on how to add the libraries, I've added all the static libraries and gave the -static option to the linker, but it is still asking for libcurl.dll

Answer (score 0):

If it is asking for libcurl.dll when you try to run the compiled binary it requires libcurl.dll at runtime. Try putting libcurl.dll in the binary's working directory.

Comment: Don' put libcurl.dll in `%WINDIR%/System32`. Please. Just put it in PATH or alongside your executable.

Comment: "working directory" isn't accurate. This might differ from where the executable is e.g. when it is called as `..\..\executable.exe`.